# croaking from a Moose BUILD method

Tags: perl, moose, carp

I want my class to blow up if the `BUILD` method fails. However, if I use `croak` to handle the error, the error gets reported from `Class/MOP/Method.pm`, rather than the caller's code. (That is to say, the caller who instantiates the object.) IOW, `croak` isn't barking far enough up the call tree.

Behold:

```
package Test;

use Moose;
use Carp 'croak';

sub BUILD {
    croak 'u r dum';
}

1;
```

Instantiating `Test` results in:

```
u r dum at /home/friedo/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Class/MOP/Method.pm line 125
```

`Carp.pm` is supposed to pay attention to a package variable called `@CARP_NOT` to know which packages to avoid, but it seems to only pay attention to one item on the list. For example, if I add this to my `Test.pm`:

```
our @CARP_NOT = ( 'Class::MOP::Method' );
```

Then the result is:

```
u r dum at /home/friedo/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Moose/Object.pm line 59
```

So I should just add *that* to the array as well, right?

```
our @CARP_NOT = ( 'Class::MOP::Method', 'Moose::Object'  );
```

Then the result is still:

```
u r dum at /home/friedo/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Moose/Object.pm line 59
```

`Moose::Object` seems unaffected.

I've been banging my head against this for a while now and can't seem to figure out what's messing it up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`make_immutable` seems to fix that. Of course, I don't know what to do if you do need your classes to be mutable.

Without `make_immutable`, `Test->new` invokes `Moose::Object->new`. If you look at the `confess` output, you'll note:

```
    Test::BUILD(...) called ...
    Class::MOP::Method::execute(...) called ...
    Moose::Object::BUILDALL(...) called ...
    Moose::Meta::Class::new_object(...) called ...
    Moose::Object::new('Test') called at ./t.pl line 17
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package Test;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

use Carp 'croak';

sub BUILD {
    croak 'u r dum';
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;

my $t = Test->new;
```

Output:

```
[sinan@archardy tmp]$ ./t.pl
u r dum at constructor Test::new (defined at ./t.pl line 14) line 28
```

From [Moose::Cookbook::Basics::Recipe7](http://metacpan.org/module/Moose::Cookbook::Basics::Recipe7):

> Second, you can no longer make changes via the metaclass API, such as adding attributes. In practice, this won't be a problem, as you rarely need to do this after first loading the class.
>
> …
>
> We strongly recommend you make your classes immutable. It makes your code much faster, with a small compile-time cost. This will be especially noticeable when creating many objects.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't even considered that. I always do `->make_immutable` as kind of an afterthought after I finish fleshing out a class.

Comment: @friedo, By promising not to change the class any further *during the current run*, Moose creates an efficient constructor for your class. It doesn't prevent you from changing the module whatsoever.

Comment: I know -- I should add it to my package boilerplate instead of trying to remember to add it when I'm done.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for a `before` method modifier.